# Local Database or JSON - Best choice to store information on Windows Phone App?

Tags: c#, json, wpf, database, windows-phone-8

I am currently creating my first windows phone app (8.1), and am wondering which is the best choice to store data (and retrieve it) :

- JSON (or XML you know)
- Local Database

I have read a bit about localDB, but I don't know if it is the best choice. I try to create a kind of quiz application, so it is used to store question and pictures.

Thank you

Comment: It depends! How much data? Do you need to query it? Do you need to sync it with a server or are the files simply shipped with the app? Is the app HTML+Javascript (e.g. a Cordova app) or native? It really depends upon many factors which you should consider. Please give more detail.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your interest :)
It is for a C# app, I will, indeed, query it, but no need to sync with a server.
In fact, it is just to store my app's data and use it. I am ok to use the 2 options, but need some information about the best practices.

Comment: I would go with Json.Net, and serialize directly your Poco objects. In observance to the KISS principle.

Answer (score 0):

Go with XML, it will be more faster and as you dont need to sync it it will be better option to use.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26688.read-data-from-xml-file-by-using-linq-on-windows-phone-8-1.aspx This link will help you to implement the same.